# Developer looking for eshop solution

Tags: e-commerce, developer-tools

I am a developer looking for an eshop solution. With the knowledge I have (Mysql, Js, Jquery, CSS, PHP) I could make it from scratch but want to avoid the hassle. Is there something well documented and easily modified on code lvl?

I am also considering WordPress+WooCommerce or PrestaShop, but hesitating considering seeing case of plugins breaking the site or cases of not finding what I need exactly. Are those cases often and how easy is to understand and modify the underlying code?